How to use nextra docs with locale in a nextjs application where locale is already being used in dashboard etc?
I already have locale in my application, URL like - http://localhost:3000/en/dashboard
I also want to implement nextra docs in my application with url like http://localhost:3000/en/docs
but unable to do that because i already use middleware for the existing app. and I can't use locale directory insde pages because i don't want to show that locale on breadcrumb or anywhere else except the url.
Tried everything but unable to solve
